# Яркий фон ответа в очереди проверок при использовании тёмной темы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, очередь-проверок, тёмная-тема

Заметил баг в очереди проверок сообщений низкого качества. Когда появляется ответ (да, именно ответ, с вопросами всё ок), то в первые секунды оно отображается со светлым фоном. Т.е. тема как бы применяется уже темная (текст уже белым цветом отображён и т.п.), но фон светлый. Вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]