# Яркий фон информационного блока при редактировании вопроса

Tags: дефект, предлагаемые-правки, тёмная-тема

Если вы предлагаете правку, информация о том, что она будет поставлена в очередь выведена белым текстом на светлом фоне.
[image: плохо читаемый текст на ярком фоне]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Яркий фон ответа в очереди проверок при использовании тёмной темы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11005/176217)